# T-SQL: How to construct latest object state based on its incremental changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

Here's the case:
Have some table that stores initial state of object and then incremental changes to its state not. Smth. like this:

```
...ID...|...Date...|....Field1...|...Field2..|...Field3..|  
...1....|..Today...|....value1...|...NULL....|...NULL....|  
...2....|..date1...|....xxx......|...NULL....|...NULL....|  
...1....|..date2...|....NULL.....|...value2..|...NULL....|  
...1....|..date3...|....init1....|...init2...|...init3...|
```

So the question is how to construct latest state for all objects that would resemble
1; Today; value1; value2; init3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a limited number of fields, you ca try this.

Otherwise, you'll have to construct a dynamic query

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbbee/21)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
Create table Test (ID int, 
                   data datetime,
                   field1 varchar(50), 
                   field2 varchar(50), 
                   field3 varchar(50))

insert into test select 1,'2013-02-14','value1',NULL,NULL
insert into test select 2,'2013-02-12','xxx',NULL,NULL
insert into test select 1,'2013-02-10',NULL,'value2',NULL 
insert into test select 1,'2013-02-04','init1','init2','init3'
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH MinDate AS (
  SELECT ID, MIN(DATA) AS DATA, MAX(DATA) AS Lastdate
  FROM Test
  GROUP BY id
  )-- Date of the initial state of each id
, D1 AS (
  SELECT ID, Field1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATA DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM TEST
  WHERE Field1 IS NOT NULL
  ) --Last date when Field 1 was changed
, D2 AS (
  SELECT ID, Field2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATA DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM TEST
  WHERE Field2 IS NOT NULL
  )
, D3 AS (
  SELECT ID, Field3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATA DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM TEST
  WHERE Field3 IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT T.ID, M.LastDate
, ISNULL(D1.Field1, T.Field1) AS Field1
, ISNULL(D2.Field2, T.Field2) AS Field2
, ISNULL(D3.Field3, T.Field3) AS Field3
FROM Test T
JOIN MinDate M ON T.id=M.id AND T.data=M.data
LEFT OUTER JOIN D1 ON T.ID=D1.ID AND D1.RowNumber=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN D2 ON T.ID=D2.ID AND D2.RowNumber=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN D3 ON T.ID=D3.ID AND D3.RowNumber=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbbee/21/0)**:

```
| ID |                        LASTDATE | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | February, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 | value1 | value2 |  init3 |
|  2 | February, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    xxx | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. That's the more or less straight way of doing that. I just thought that there's some beautiful solution that for great amount of columns. Cuz current solution will perform very slowly if many row and columns in table.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH latestDate
AS
(
SELECT  ID, DATE, Field1, Field2, Field3,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC) x
FROM    tableName
)
SELECT ID, DATE, Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM    latestDate
WHERE x = 1
```

Comment: Actually, this is returning `1; Today; Value1; null; null` so I don't think it's the right answer

Comment: Exactly! It's not about ranking. It's about grouping by ID and selecting the latest not null value for each field within group and combining all that stuff into one row for each group.